# Check if a two columns are completely numeric in a csv using awk

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, scripting, csv

I have a csv with columns A & B as below which has numeric or alphanumeric data.I need to write column C such that if,

- A or B is blank -> write "Error" in C
- A or B not numeric -> write "Error" in C
- A & B are numeric and A!=B -> write "Mismatch" in C
- A & B are numeric and A=B -> write "Match" in C.

My code is as below which is not working fine.Please help me out here.

```
awk -F ',' ' NR==1; NR >1 {OFS=",";
if ($1 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/ || $2 ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/)
   print $1,$2,"Error";
else if ($1 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/ || $2 ~ /^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
   print $1,$2,"Error";
else if ($1 == /^([[:digit:]]+)$/ && $2 == /^([[:digit:]]+)$/ && $1 != $2)
    print $1,$2,"Mismatch";
else if ($1 == /^([[:digit:]]+)$/ && $2 == /^([[:digit:]]+)$/ && $1 == $2)
    print $1,$2,"Match";
  } ' ~/input.csv > ~/output.csv
```

Sample input data:

```
232,2w323   
343,   
   ,454  
565,677  
fg66,   
   ,ghg6  
gf6,ghugyu6
```

Comment: Hello, this is a bit confusing. A and B are what fields in the .csv? 1st and 2nd or 2nd and 3rd or 1st and 3rd?

Comment: A and B are 1st and 2nd columns.. @suspectus

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: why do you use `$3` for second column ?

Comment: Also, please fix the spaces in the file. Your current input has trailing spaces, so `677     ` does not match `/^[[:digit:]]+$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you fixed the spaces in your input, you can use:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS=FS=","}
NR==1 { print; next }
$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {
    print $1,$2,($1==$2)?"Match":"Mismatch"
    next
}
{ print $1,$2,"Error" }
' input.csv > output.csv
```

Output:

```
232,2w323,Error
343,   ,Error
   ,454,Error
565,677,Mismatch
fg66,  ,Error
   ,ghg6,Error
gf6,ghugyu6,Error
```

Comment: Thanks.Working perfectly fine.Just wanted to include NR==1; NR >1 in order to retain and skip header record processing.Where should i include that?

Comment: I added that ...